# Errors with OpenWeather API

Tags: javascript, html, api, http, p5.js

I made a weather forecast web app which uses p5.js. It runs perfectly on my localhost. Why does this keep popping up on github page:

> Mixed Content: The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but
>   requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint ''. This request
>   has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

github: https://github.com/VlatkoStojkoski/OpenWeather-API

github page: https://vlatkostojkoski.github.io/OpenWeather-API/

Comment: Your site is using `https` and so the browser will prevent requests that is not `https` . You should change API endpoint to `HTTPS`. You can see here: https://github.com/VlatkoStojkoski/OpenWeather-API/pull/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the GitHub page is loading the API request that uses a `http` connection instead of the required `https`. Try accessing the API server on a secure connection and it should work.

Comment: But how do I access it with secure connection

Comment: Maybe use server-side JS to serve it somewhere else?